# How to insert data in 4 tables with one form

Tags: mysql, join

I am having trouble inserting into multiple tables using a single form in a news project.

```
insert into news JOIN news2 JOIN news3 JOIN news4(title,image,news,descn,category) values('$title','$image','$news','$descn','$category')
```

Comment: Please give us more details. Read: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: why do you apparently have 4 news tables with the same structure? And you want to insert the same record into all of them? Why on earth would you copy the same data 4 times? It makes no sense (quite apart from the fact that this syntax is not allowed anyway).

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. INSERT statements always just use one table. If you want to insert into multiple tables and make sure that all inserts are considered as one atomic operation, use transactions. Like this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO x VALUES ...
INSERT INTO y VALUES ...
INSERT INTO z VALUES ...
COMMIT;
```

When an error happens, you do `ROLLBACK;` instead of a commit and all statements of that transaction are undone.

On another note, when you have tables like news, news2, news3 and so on, this smells like bad database design. You should seriously reconsider that, as the goal of a relational database used for transactional workload usually is to avoid redundant data. To achieve this normalization is used. Here's a link to a [tutorial](http://holowczak.com/database-normalization/). (I haven't read it, but after a quick glance after googling it looks promising)

Another note: When you join tables, provide a join condition. Otherwise you get every row of one table combined with every row from every other table, which can be a HUGE resultset. You usually don't want that. Consider reading a tutorial about SQL as well.